# How to get custom table next id to be saved?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, increment-id

In magento1 - My scenario is saving an image to a folder. Why I am using id is I have to save a lot of items (images, pdf) into the same folder as it is all related to this item.
When new data is created I want to save the file in that data id -> for supposing I have already 4 items then added fifth then I can check total rows and increment 1 and make a folder. But suppose I deleted the fifth item and adding another item so the primary key - unique id to be saved in DB will be 6 and not five.
I can use

```
Mage::getModel('productlabel/productlabel')->save()
```

and get id by

```
Mage::getModel('productlabel/productlabel')->getId()
```

but not preferred as it might get delay/error in saving then already the values will be saved and the files will not be.
I used the following but it is all returning null values

```
Mage::getModel('productlabel/productlabel')->getNextId();
Mage::getModel('productlabel/productlabel')->getLastId();
```

Is there any method to get the next id to be saved in table.

EDIT: IS there any method to get the same. Send a reply ASAP as i am stuck with it for past 2 days.